# Redis: Is it possible to get just one value of a Set by its key?

Tags: redis

I have a Set named 'Projects' with many key-value pairs and I want to retrieve one of the values by providing its key. I checked the redis doc but I only found how to retrieve the entire Set. Is it possible to just retrieve one value by providing its key?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your concept of Set does not match Redis'.

All members of a set in Redis are stored in a single key. Therefore you can't access members individually by a key.

You should use hashes: http://www.redis.io/commands#hash

`HSET key field value` does what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh I see. So for example to get a particular project inside the Project Hash I would do HGET Project project_1 and that would return me the value stored at that key. Correct?